# SQL Server tough Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I'm having an issue writing a tough query. I have the following table (as an example)

```
fusionId | productId | departmentId
    1    |     1     |       1
    2    |     1     |       2
    3    |     2     |       1
    4    |     3     |       2
```

I want a query that I can pass two `departmentId`'s to (1,2) and for the query to return the `productId` only if both `departmentId` match the same `productId`

So for example if I sent the `departmentId`'s 1 & 2 I would get the result

```
productId
    1
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT productId 
FROM YourTable
WHERE departmentId IN (1,2)
GROUP BY productId 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT departmentId) = 2
```

Or

```
SELECT productId 
FROM YourTable
WHERE departmentId = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT productId 
FROM YourTable
WHERE departmentId = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table Temporary 
(
    fusionId  int,
    productId  int,
    departmentId int,
)

insert into Temporary values (1,1,1),(2,1,2),(3,2,1),(4,3,2)

Select productId  from Temporary 
Where productId in (Select productId from Temporary where departmentId = 1) and departmentId =2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT productId 
FROM YourTable
WHERE departmentId IN (1,2)
GROUP bY productId 
HAVING COUNT(productId) > 1
```